# Adding values from one dataframe to another based on two matching conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes below:

dput output df1:

```
structure(list(Location = c("1100 2ND AVENUE", "1100 2ND AVENUE", 
"1100 2ND AVENUE", "1100 2ND AVENUE", "1100 2ND AVENUE", "1100 2ND AVENUE"
), `Ivend Name` = c("3 Mskt 1.92oz", "Almond Joy 1.61oz", "Aquafina 20oz", 
"BCanyonChptleAdzuk1.5oz", "BlkForest FrtSnk 2.25oz", "BluDimndSmkhseAlmd1.5oz"
), `Category Name` = c("Candy", "Candy", "Water", "Salty Snacks", 
"Candy", "Nuts/Trailmix"), Calories = c(240, 220, 0, 215, 193, 
260), Sugars = c("36", "20", "0", "2", "32", "2"), Month = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", 
"Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep"), class = "factor"), 
    Products_available_per_machine = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Units_sold = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Total_Sales = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Spoils = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Building = c("1100 2ND", "1100 2ND", "1100 2ND", 
    "1100 2ND", "1100 2ND", "1100 2ND"), Item = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Beverage", "Food"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "2019", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000233561b1ef0>)
```

dput output df2:

```
structure(list(`Date Ran` = structure(c(1548892800, 1551312000, 
1553817600, 1556582400, 1561680000, 1564531200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019), Month = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "June", 
"July"), Location = c("SEA18", "SEA18", "SEA18", "SEA18", "SEA18", 
"SEA18"), Building = c("Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria", 
"Alexandria", "Alexandria", "Alexandria"), Population = c(1177, 
1179, 1178, 1156, 1163, 1163)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to pull the pop col from DF 2 and add it to Dataframe 1 based on 'Building' and 'Month' in the order population is filled in DF2.

I tried this command using merge but the col is NULL when I execute:

```
df_2019_final1$Population <- df_2019_pop$Population[match(df_2019_final1$Month, df_2019_pop$Month, df_2019_final1$Building, df_2019_pop$Building)]

subset_df_pop <- df_2019_pop[, c("Month", "Building", "Population")]


updated_2019_test <- merge(df_2019_final1, subset_df_pop, by = c('Month', 'Building'))
```

Both produce NULLS and a blank DF

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `match` takes only 2 vectors `match(x, table, nomatch = NA_integer_, incomparables = NULL)`

Comment: Can you try with `merge(df1, df2, by = c('Month', 'Building'))`

Comment: I just tried merging and it outputed a blank df. It for someone reason brought all the columns over instead of Month/Building

Comment: You need to subest the second data  by including only thoes columns + Populatoin i.e. `merge(df1, df2[, c("Month", "Building", "Population")], by = c('Month', 'Building'))`

Comment: I edited my question with your solution and still got a blank df after.

Comment: Can you please edit with the `dput` of both examples for testing

Comment: Can I use head dput? Both dfs are quite large

Comment: Just use the same example data i.e. head

Comment: Adjusted now - thanks your help @akrun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the datasets, the 'Month' is abbreviated and in the second it is full name.  We can adjust to either one of those formats and the `merge` would work

```
df2$MonthN <- month.abb[match(df2$Month, month.name)]
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2[, c("MonthN", "Building", "Population")], 
             by = c('Month' = 'MonthN', 'Building'))
```

---

Or with `merge`

```
merge(df1, df2[, c("MonthN", "Building", "Population")], 
   by.x = c('Month', 'Building'), by.y = c('MonthN', 'Building'), all.x = TRUE)
```

Note: The Population column on the merged dataset will be `NA` based on the example as "Building" values are different in the subset datasets

Comment: Thank you so much for the help - will population be filled for the buildings that do match?

Comment: @Dinho In that case, you have to only `merge` with `'Month' i.e. remove `Buliding' from the `by`

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not getting the output I need. I am trying to have the same layout from the main df but just add pop data to respective areas. I guess I need to remove non-matching Buildings to make this work

Comment: @Dinho That is a different issue, but it can do the match only based on the matching values for those `by` variables

Comment: I got it to work - my "building" for both DFs in terms of font were different (One was all caps and the other wasn't). Used Toupper and wa able to get Pops filled for matched BUilding IDs. Thanks for you help my man!